# Senate bypass Majority Leader

Tags: united-states, congress, senate-rules

According to [this answer](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/35283/11278) citing the senate website:

> Senate rules also permit a measure to be placed directly on the
>   calendar when introduced or received from the House. This process
>   permits senators to bypass referral to a committee they believe
>   unsympathetic. Alternatively, if a committee fails to report a
>   measure, a new measure with exactly the same provisions may be
>   introduced and placed directly on the calendar.

If so, how has McConnell managed to block the House Bill twice?

Comment: That does not state who places it on the calendar. For all we know it is still the responsibility of the majority leader. From my reading of the quote it is just to get around roadblocks in committee not roadblocks with the majority leader.

Answer (score 5):

Look a little further down in the next paragraph of the [article](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/common/briefing/Senate_legislative_process.htm#3) quoted from that post and you will see this.  I am responsible for the highlighting.

> **The Senate accords its majority leader prime responsibility for
>   scheduling. He may carry out this responsibility by moving that the
>   Senate proceed to consider a particular matter.** By precedent, he and
>   the minority leader are recognized preferentially, and by custom only
>   he (or his designee) makes motions or requests affecting when the
>   Senate will meet and what it will consider.

Notice that this is BY PRECEDENT only and only to prevent a chaotic amount of bills from being introduced.  Any member of the Senate can introduce something to the floor.  This can be prevented by objection of any member of the Senate.

> This marks the third time that McConnell has blocked House-passed
>   government funding bills in the past two weeks. **Under Senate rules,
>   any senator can ask for consent to vote on or pass a bill, but any
>   senator can object.**

Referenced [here](https://thehill.com/blogs/floor-action/senate/425945-mcconnell-blocks-bill-to-reopen-most-of-government).

Comment: As a side note, Senate Republicans could elect a different Senate Majority Leader (since McConnell is blocking / not scheduling budget votes)